# Rounded corners for a tableView in viewController

Tags: objective-c, tableview, rounded-corners

I can´t find out how to make rounded corners on the tableView I have in a viewController.

viewcontroller.m:

I added the framework and imported:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And also in voidDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view.layer setCornerRadius:7.0];

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController` or do you have a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: I added UITAbleView to a UIViewController. But I solved it now. The right code is [self.tableView.layer setCornerRadius: 7.0]; of course. But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
   #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
   self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
   self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```